# Cannot Get Partial View To Show -- Jade/Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, pug

I am using this boilerplate: https://github.com/jakemmarsh/angularjs-gulp-browserify-boilerplate

I added support for Jade in regards to Gulp and it builds out the Jade files into HTML files.

When it kicks up the browser, it shows the index.html with the header/footer partials loaded in.  That being said, it doesn't load in the home.html partial that Angular should be loading in with the UI-Router.

I am very new to Angular, so I am sure that I am missing something very simple.

Index HTML file (built from Jade):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <!--title('{{title}}')-->
    <meta name="description" content="{{description}}">
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{keywords}}">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/handheld.css" media="screen and (min-width:0px) and (max-width:1024px)">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tablet.css" media="screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1024px)">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width:767px)">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <header id="header">
        <div class="page clearfix">
          <div class="top">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">khaccsupport</a></li>
              <li><a href="">khaccsupport</a></li>
              <li><a href="">shane@khaccounts.net</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><a href="/" class="logo"><img src="../images/logo.png"></a>
          <section class="secondary-header">
            <nav class="navigation">
              <ul>
                <li class="top-link"><a href="buy-world-of-warcraft-wow-accounts/" class="top-link">Buy WoW Accounts</a></li>
                <li class="top-link"><a href="sell-wow-accounts/" class="top-link">Sell WoW Accounts</a></li>
                <li class="top-link"><a href="customer-reviews-feedback" class="top-link">Reviews / Feedback</a></li>
                <li class="top-link"><a href="buy-sell-wow-accounts-faq" class="top-link">FAQ</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </section>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="fb-frame">
        <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fkhaccounts&amp;amp;width=450&amp;amp;height=35&amp;amp;colorscheme=light&amp;amp;layout=standard&amp;amp;action=like&amp;amp;show_faces=false&amp;amp;send=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="page">
          <div ui-view></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-wrapper index-page">
        <footer id="footer">
          <div class="page">
            <div class="footer-content clearfix">
              <div class="links-wrapper clearfix">
                <section class="footer-links nav">
                  <h4>Navigation</h4>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="/buy-world-of-warcraft-wow-accounts">Buy High End Elite Premium WoW Accounts</a><br><a href="/sell-wow-accounts">Sell High End Elite Premium WoW Accounts</a><br><a href="/">High End Elite Premium WoW Accounts For Sale</a><br><a href="/customer-reviews-feedback">KHAccounts.net Customer Reviews & Feedback</a><br><a href="/buy-sell-wow-accounts-faq">KHAccounts.net Buy & Sell WoW Accounts FAQ</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul>
                    <li></li>
                    <div class="secondary-footer"><a href="" class="footer-logo"><img src="../images/footer-logo.png"></a><span class="copyright">©2015 Knucklehead Accounts -- All Rights Reserved.</span></div>
                  </ul>
                </section>
                <section class="footer-links reference">
                  <h4>Referral Links</h4>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.maskedarmory.com">Anonymous WoW Armory Profiles</a><br><a href="http://www.maskedcrusader.com">Trade WoW Accounts</a><br><a href="http://www.maskedcrusader.com/buy-sell-trade-mmorpg/">MMO Game Account Trading</a><br><a href="http://www.maskedcrusader.com/buy-sell-trade-world-warcraft-wow/">WoW Trading Forum</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://www.arenarating.com/category/rbg-rating-boost/world-of-warcraft/">RBG Rating Boost</a><br><a href="https://www.arenarating.com/category/arena-boost-3v3/world-of-warcraft/">Arena Rating Boost</a><br><a href="http://www.twinkinfo.com">TwinkInfo.com</a><br><a href="http://www.twinkinfo.com/forums">TwinkInfo.com Forums</a><br><a href="http://www.twinkinfo.com/forums/f200/">Twinking Guides</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </section>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Routes.js file:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngInject
 */
function Routes($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $stateProvider
  .state('Home', {
    url: '/',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
    template: '../views/home.html',
    title: 'Home'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

}

module.exports = Routes;
```

Comment: Is there any console error

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  It turns out I needed to be using TemplateURL, not Template in the route.js.